# Escape Quotes in line_item title shopify breaking API feed

Tags: shopify

I’m writing middleware for client fulfillment and noticed that some of the JSON from the order callback/paid hook isn't validating correctly because double quotes are included in the body.

This is breaking client-side JSON deserialization because the double quotes in the body of the webhook HTTP POST aren't being escaped.

Is there anything I can do about this besides forcing the client to remove the double quotes from the title?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error, all my tests are producing correctly escaped json. Please have a go at reproducing this in a test store with some dummy products and post the results here. Thanks.